# create list of variables that satisfy condition without manually typing them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to do this:

```
cwd = Path(os.getcwd())
target = 'data/aggregations/'

# want this:
agg_12.to_csv(cwd / target / 'agg_12.csv', index=False)
```

for each of my dataframe variables:

```
agg_12 = make_agg_12(df)
agg_11 = make_agg_11(agg_12)
agg_10 = make_agg_10(agg_11)
agg_9 = make_agg_9(agg_12)
agg_8 = make_agg_8(agg_9)
agg_7 = make_agg_7(agg_9)
agg_6 = make_agg_6(agg_7)
agg_5 = make_agg_5(agg_7)
agg_4 = make_agg_4(agg_8)
agg_3 = make_agg_3(agg_8)
agg_2 = make_agg_2(agg_6)
agg_1 = make_agg_1(agg_2)
```

It doesn't seem pythonic to write it for each one.

This solution works (but...):

```
""" as a convenience, this step saves the aggregations locally so this doesn't need to run again. """
cwd = Path(os.getcwd())
target = 'data/aggregations/'

# template: agg_12.to_csv(cwd / target / 'agg_12.csv', index=False)
agg_list = [agg_12, agg_11, agg_10, agg_9, agg_8, agg_7, agg_6, agg_5, agg_4, agg_3, agg_2, agg_1]
agg_str = ['agg_12', 'agg_11', 'agg_10', 'agg_9', 'agg_8', 'agg_7', 'agg_6', 'agg_5', 'agg_4', 'agg_3', 'agg_2', 'agg_1']

for agg_i, agg in enumerate(agg_list):
    agg_name = agg_str[agg_i]
    agg.to_csv(cwd / target / f'{agg_name}.csv', index=False)
    print('wrote: ', f'{agg_name}.csv')
```

However, what if I had 100s or 1000s of df variables that I wanted to do this for.  How can I create a list of them without typing them out manually?

I have tried using dir(), which of course only gives me the string name of the variable, not an actual reference.

Comment: You need to fundamentally re-design your program. Why do you have 12 variables with the same name except for an increasing number? These dataframes *should have been in a container to begin with*. Here, a `list` would be eminently reasonable. Now you are abusing `dir()` to try to dynamically access your variables using strings. Don't do that.

Comment: Also you are using the old results as input to get the new ones, so as per the above comment, you should really look into modifying your strategy!

Comment: @Aditya, that's entirely unrelated to the question.  And, it also happens to be efficient:  it's a massive source dataframe, and I'm summarizing to different levels of granularity: so, using the already summarized aggregations is a lot faster, as they're already reduced in size.

Comment: Apologies, i now see what's happening; Just curious, have you attempted using ```globals()``` as well?

Comment: @Aditya, no, but that sounds reasonable.  I'm currently testing a list which holds each of the agg_1 - agg_12 df's.  And simply looping through that.  However, what if I had 1000s of df that I wanted to save as CSV.  There must be a way to look up all my variables, that fit the parameter `startswith('agg_')` and save them.  Otherwise, a user would need to type out all 1000 df variables.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga:  I am testing the use of a list, which should work.  Thanks.  However, what if I had 1000s of df that I wanted to save as CSV. There must be a way to look up all my variables, that fit the parameter startswith('agg_') and save them. Otherwise, a user would need to type out all 1000 df variables.

Comment: Ahh not sure but any reason for not caching inside the ```make_agg_k``` itself ?

Comment: @ColinMac In that situation, you should still use a list.

Comment: The list works.  I will update my question to reflect the root question: how to build such a list of all variables that fit a condition, without having to type them out.

Comment: **Don't make the variables in the first place.** Use a list **from the start**.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I'm not sure what you mean.  These are rather large dataframes.  But, even if they weren't large, I don't follow.

Comment: Instead of making `df_1`, `df_2`, ..., `df_24531`, etc. variables, one per dataframe, make a list of dataframes. (What would the size of the dataframes have to do with anything?)

Comment: So, there isn't a way to perform some action, across a large list of variables, without explicitly typing out the list?  And, yes, I understand, there is the alternative method of making these variables within a list or a dictionary or something.   It just strikes me as odd that you can't access the variables using some of the built in functionality.